# get Max value without group by 1 row sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max, greatest-n-per-group

i need help to get a value from a table without grouping one field.

the table design is like this

```
Progress    DocNum    Project
---------------------------
30        10         1111
70        11         1111
30        10         1112
100       12         1111
70        13         1112
```

then i want data like this.
get the max progress for each project, without grouping DocNum

```
Progress    DocNum    Project
---------------------------
100       12         1111
70        13         1112
```

how someone can help me.
thankyou very much before

Comment: please tag your dbms.

Comment: I added the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag. This question has been answered hundreds of times on Stack Overflow. Follow the tag and see the solutions.

Comment: @McNets i user Sql server 2012

Comment: Why have you accepted an answer that  uses group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this

```
SELECT t.progress, t.docnum, t.project
FROM table_name t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(progress) max_progress,
        project
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY project
) mt
ON t.project = mt.project
    AND t.progress = mt.progress;
```

Or this

```
SELECT progress, docnum, project
FROM table_name 
WHERE (progress, project) IN (
        SELECT MAX(progress) max_progress,
            project
        FROM table_name
        GROUP BY project
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions row_number to get one row with max progress per project:

```
Select *
From (
  Select t.*,
    Row_number() over (partition by project order by progress desc) rn
  From your_table t
) t where rn = 1
```

If there are multiple rows with max progress per project and you want to retrieve all of them, use rank instead:

```
Select *
From (
  Select t.*,
    Rank() over (partition by project order by progress desc) rnk
  From your_table t
) t where rnk = 1
```

#### Note:

Both the above queries read the table only once. The accepted solution reads the table twice.

Comment: Should we use `ROW_NUMBER()` or rank for this? I think with that we will have to calculate row_number for each record so this will become a big problem with large dataset.

Comment: I didn't blame you, I just want to ask. After seaching with `ROW_NUMBER VS MAX`, I got the aswer is `It Depends` :)). For a simple mind, not count for index, optimize..., your query's complexity is like `for x in 1..n (for y in 1..x)` and be O(n* n), and the above solution is MAX + IN (or JOIN) = O(n) + O(n* n) = O(n* n) too

Comment: @PhamX.Bach - Of course it depends. Sometimes, you'll think correlated queries will be slower but they outperform the uncorrelated queries. In data world, a fast solution now may not be as fast tomorrow.

Comment: Yep, and so we have CBO :x